# Android - Firebase: after cleaning cache remote config is not delivered correctly

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-remote-config

Trying to integrate Android with Firebase. After cleaning cache or deliting app remote config is not delivered correctly (we see only default value) or in callback OnCompleteListener method isSuccessful returns false.

On the user side that causes not regular and fast applying changes in remote config, which makes Firebase useless.

Could you advice something? Does anyone faced the issue? BTW all is ok on iOS.

Comment: When I run with version 9.4.0, App Info "Clear cache" does not clear the config data. App Info "Clear data" does clear it, requiring a re-fetch and re-activate.  What version are you running?  When the fetch completion listener returns `task.isSuccessful==false`, what is `task.getException.getMessage()`?